# Forwarding ports over RDP protocol

Tags: remote-desktop, port-forwarding, rdp

I was assigned a task that needs to be performed on the corporate virtual machine. I'm connecting to a Windows 7 remote desktop over OpenConnect VPN. From there I have access to all network resources (mainly databases).

It's very tiring to work like this, so I though about little improvements.

Is it possible to forward some ports to local host (*nix machine) over RDP without admin privileges on Windows host? I have heard about [rdp2tcp](https://github.com/V-E-O/rdp2tcp) project, but it does not seem to be maintained over 6 years.

Comment: `It's very tiring to work like this` - Really? What's so tiring about it?

Comment: @joeqwerty, typically you have everything you need on your "source" workstation. As an example, consider that you have some piece of software locally to manage DBs. If you could forward access to ports of the corporate DB, you could use that program right away. As it stands, you need to install another piece of software to the workstation being accessed remotely. If it's a different piece of software, the situation gets worse as you have to re-learn.

Comment: @joeqwerty, the environment is setup with all necessary tools. The problem is with the UX, the whole desktop is transmitted over the network, I'm experiencing lagging which makes work annoying.

Answer (score 1):

No. It would evade any kind of security by tunneling unknown and untrusted traffic into the network.

You're already connected to your employer through VPN, so ask the employers IT staff to open up ports for you (on the VPN) if you need them.

Comment: Once you let the user into your network all bets are off anyway, so I find this line of reasoning to be convoluted. SSH allows any sort of forwardings (TCP, Unix-domain sockets, X, SSH agent) and even implements a SOCKS proxy, if needed, and the server admins do not experience any sort of problems with this.

Comment: This is not answering the question (it's saying "it's a bad idea, try this instead" instead of actually answering the question). (sorry for necroposting, it's just frustrating that I can't find an answer to this anywhere)